# Web address for subdomain changing as it proceeds through directory? Using Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have set up a subdomain in the path /public_html/SUBDOMAIN... when I load the index file for the subdomain, it all works well, and uses the web address

http://www.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com

However, as I direct to the sample page Wordpress has provided, the web address changes to

http://www.DOMAIN.com/SUBDOMAIN/sample-page

Why is this? How do I keep the structure of the web address consistent? Thankyou.